# PulseAudio ~/.pulse/default.pa not used

Tags: pulseaudio

I have pulseaudio configuration stored in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, but i want to create new config outside as described in [default.pa man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/default.pa). I have created my config in `~/.pulse/default.pa`. As I understand from the man page this should be used before the `/etc/pulse` version, but after restarting the pulseaudio, it still uses the old config.

Below command I use to start pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --disallow-module-loading
```

Why is it not using the new config? How can I alter the default configuration?

Comment: Why would a system instance read the user's config?

Comment: Fair point, but i was wondering if there is a mechanism to do such thing as i described but system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the config via an environment variable like described in `man pulseaudio`:

```
PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG=/home/username/.pulse/default.pa pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --disallow-module-loading
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running pulseaudio as a system wide service using systemd and you're trying to remap a sink and set it as the default sink, the service will ignore `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

e.g.

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.usb-YOUR_DEVICE-00.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono sink_properties="device.description='Mono'"
set-default-sink mono
```

You can get around this by setting your default device directly in `/etc/pulse/system.pa`.

You can check if you're running a system wide service by running the following command and reading the warning messages at the bottom.

```
systemctl status pulseaudio
● pulseaudio.service - PulseAudio Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-10-04 14:42:02 BST; 16min ago
   Main PID: 354 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 2059)
        CPU: 25.745s
     CGroup: /system.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─354 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --realtime --disallow-exit --no-cpu-limit

Oct 04 14:42:02 picroft pulseaudio[354]: N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling SHM mode.
Oct 04 14:42:02 picroft pulseaudio[354]: N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling exit idle time.
Oct 04 14:42:02 picroft pulseaudio[354]: W: [pulseaudio] main.c: OK, so you are running PA in system mode. Please make sure that you actually do want to do that.
```